# Survey regression in R with singleton PSUs

Tags: r, regression, survey

I am completely new to R, just downloaded and installed it today. I am familiar with SAS and Stata; I am using R because I have found out that in survey regression analysis, R is capable of using data that have stratum with one PSU. However, I cannot figure out how to write the code at all.

Here is what I have done so far: read a Stata dataset and save the .RData file. I have also put in the MASS, pscl, and survey (for svyglm) packages.

Here's what I need to do:
1) I am using survey data, so I have a "weight" variable, a "strata" variable, and a "PSU" variable. I need to incorporate those; I know how to use svyset in Stata, but no idea in R.
2) I have stratum with singleton PSUs. I need to use an option called survey.lonely.psu I believe, and I have no idea where to even begin with that. This is the reason why I am using R instead of Stata as I do not want to collapse stratum or delete observations.
3) The types of regression models I have to run: survey negative binomial, survey zero-inflated negative binomial (need to also determine the predictors of zeros), survey logistic, and survey OLS regression.
4)I also really can't make much sense in R of how to write the model in R code. In Stata, I can simply write the model as:

svy: nbreg dependent_var independent_var1 independent_var2 independent_var3

I can't figure out how to do that at all in R.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [survey package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html). Here is an example of how to define the survey design you have specified and how to run a linear regression on these data. I assume that the dataset has already been loaded.

```
require(survey)
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
design1 <- svydesign(id = ~psuid, strata = ~stratvar, weights = ~weightvar, data = mydata)
model1 <- svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, design = design1)
summary(model1)
```

IMHO, [Thomas Lumley's homepage](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/) is an excellent starting point for this kind of things.

Rather than only installing the survey package, you can install the [Official Statistics task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/OfficialStatistics.html):

```
install.packages("ctv")
install.views("OfficialStatistics")
```

This task view gives you a rather nice and complete toolbox to work with survey data.

Note that with Stata's `svyset` command you have basically the same possibilities than you have in R to handle singleton sampling units.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was helpful. I do have another question, though. How do I use zero-inflated count models for surveys (specifically zero-inflated negative binomial), and survey logistic models?

Comment: The svyglm command is a kind of wrapper for the glm command. Thus, it is possible to fit survey logistic regression models. As far as the zero inflated negbin models are concerned, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to figure out how to do this for a while. I know what you should read, but I haven't read them enough.

- [Survey statistics overview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/OfficialStatistics.html)
- [Survey package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf)